# Filtering googlemaps with markerclusterer for displaying only markers visible on the screen (on a sidebar) - contents loaded via xml

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I am running this website at http://arquitectospelomundo.com which is googlemap based.
Thanks to this community I have already managed to make it read data from a xml file, process it into a markerclusterer object and make it display a sidebar with the content as well.
Now I was looking to see if it was possible to filter that sidebar with only the markers seen on the screen (zooming in would remove items from that list).
Have already tried with no success since markerclusterer is giving me a hard time.
Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It is possible, I have examples that do it, just not using markerclusterer.  What does your code look like (where you tried to do it and couldn't get it to work)?

Comment: Yes! You and your great tutorials are what have been teaching a lot on google maps api ! Including populating the sidebar, the loading from xml... I am pretty sure it was again with examples form geocodezip.com  that I tried to do what I wanted but have not managed to make it work with the clusterer). Thanks for the great site you have there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe the bounds_changed-event of the map and then loop over the markers and check if the bounds of the map contains the markers:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'bounds_changed',function(){
var bounds=map.getBounds();
$('#side_bar a').each(function(i,e){
  $(e).add($(e).next('br'))
    .css('display',(bounds.contains(gmarkers[i].getPosition()))?'block':'none');
});
});
```

This will filter the sidebar-elements, but lazyload will not notice the change. But you may force lazyload to load the images by triggering the scroll-event:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'bounds_changed',function(){
var bounds=map.getBounds();
$('#side_bar a').each(function(i,e){
  var c=bounds.contains(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
  $(e).add($(e).next('br')).css('display',c?'block':'none')
   .find('img').trigger((c)?'scroll':'void');
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you really pointed me out in the right direction! This work yet it is CPU intensive and any scroll or pan makes the map freeze for a second or two. But with this I may now implement, perhaps, a button ("Show architects from this area", for eg.). PS: I am placing your code just before the markerCluster declaration (if I place it next to the other event listeners it hangs the map). Thank you for the help!

Comment: you may use `idle` instead `bounds_changed`, this will fire less often

Comment: Thanks, that helps... still may be asking for too much CPU :/ (my machine is not bad...) but I'll see what I can do! :)

Comment: I think adding a delay helps, making the idle listener fire only after 1.5 seconds. Thanks again! This is how it is now (my localhost only yet): `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', (function ()
{
 var delay;
 return function()
 {
  clearTimeout(delay);
  timer = setTimeout(function()
  {
   var bounds=map.getBounds();
   $('#side_bar a').each(function(i,e)
   {
    var c=bounds.contains(gmarkers[i].getPosition());
    $(e).add($(e).next('br')).css('display',c?'block':'none') .find('img').trigger((c)?'scroll':'void');
   });
  }, 1500);
 }
}()));`